# Merging 2 WordPress databases with both corresponding and unique content + minor tweaks

Tags: sql, database, wordpress, merge, synchronization

A little intro: I've been developing a WordPress website at my company, for a big, international client. Since it's launch some time ago, we've obviously had some improvements, tweaks, bugs, etc. We have a couple of developers here, working with a clean local - staging - production workflow, syncing our local environments with git. When changes have to be made, we pull a version from the live site, make changes locally, upload it on a staging site, and after approval and final testing, deploy to the live website.

Our last round of changes was a big one, recoding a lot of our theme files as well as tweaking the database a bit. After uploading it on the staging site for approval however, things went awry. Our contact person got confused with the versions, and went on to publish new posts and edit pages on the live site, as well as create new content on the staging site. I don't mean 'do the same thing on both'... they did some work on each.

Now I somehow have to sync the two, so I can deploy the site and move on to further development (we also need the site live because we wrote an API that communicates between the client's large corporate site, and it's smaller subsidiaries' sites)

I checked out these posts already:

[How can I merge two MySQL tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725556/how-can-i-merge-two-mysql-tables)

[Merge 2 SQL Server databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932946/merge-2-sql-server-databases)

[Merging wordpress Databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23525977/merging-wordpress-databases)

And I tried multiple built-in and plugin solutions.
Having a very large website a lot of custom fields (ACF) and having them translated in 4 languages, makes this even harder, I think. Exporting and importing has broken something on each try (often with the translation), and plugins like Database Sync only offer a complete replacement of the db's, and thus losing the unique content each site has. I have some knowledge of SQL queries, and could freshen these up a bit more, but I don't really see how I could manually merge the two sql-files.

In short: I need to sync 2 databases from 2 slightly different versions of mostly the same website. There is unique and duplicate content, as well as minor tweaks in WP.